# Report approval functionality?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, invoice

I am working on a weekly reporting project with SSRS. We currently have an Azure SQL server running a sample of the report, which will be delivered on a weekly basis. The report is distributed to a team to validate the data is correct. What we need from this group is either an "approval" or a message with the required changes. What options do we have in SSRS that could support the communication in this approval processing? I am am imagining having another table that would list Approval (y/n) and comments if the it is not approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rite. One option is to have Anchor link for approve and one for comments and clicking on them you can call a report or a procedure to insert the data against that report and used for further processing.YOu can even configure SQL mail to the developers as communication.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I am unfamiliar on how one could embed this in a link. Could you point me in the direction a resource?